# How to get value from a WEIRD JSON RESPONSE

Tags: python, json, scrapy

I was trying to get data from this `API` link:
https://www.longandfoster.com/include/ajax/api.aspx?op=SearchAgents&firstname=&lastname=&page=1&pagesize=200

If you go to the above link you will see a weird JSON response. The keys and values are not properly displayed.

I converted the duct response into a list and iterate over it. I got the response but the value against the key is not printing, instead, it's returning None

> {'Name': None}

import scrapy
import json

```
class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'main'
    # allowed_domains = ['longandfoster.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.longandfoster.com/include/ajax/api.aspx?op=SearchAgents&firstname=&lastname=&page=1&pagesize=200']

    def parse(self, response):
        # resp = json.loads(response.body)
        resp_list = []
        resp = json.loads(response.body)
        resp_list.append(resp)

        for each in resp_list:
            name = each.get('DisplayName')

            yield {
                "Name": name,
            }
```

Comment: What is the particular error you are getting?

Comment: I updated the question. This is the error I am getting: Error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: `json.loads(response.json()["Entity"])`

Comment: Sounds like each is a string, and you might be expecting it to be a dictionary

Comment: The JSON response is a dictionary. How can I come over this issue?

Comment: @AwaisAhmedSheikh, wat? o_O JSON response interpreted as `dict` in python, what is the problem?

Comment: @OlvinRoght please go to this link and you will see the response in a dict

https://www.longandfoster.com/include/ajax/api.aspx?op=SearchAgents&firstname=&lastname=&page=1&pagesize=200

Comment: @AwaisAhmedSheikh, look in my previous comment, replace `json.loads(response.body)` in your code with code I've provided and enjoy.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I tried your method but it didn't work. I converted the dictionary into list and iterate over it and succeded but I am not getting the value against the key. It's returning None but the error is gone.

Comment: @AwaisAhmedSheikh, update code in question to your current version.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I just updated it, you can take a look at it.

Comment: @AwaisAhmedSheikh, I don't see line I've posted in comments in your updated code, sooo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `json.loads()` two times

```
 resp = json.loads( json.loads(response.body)['Entity'] )
```

and then your code works.

---

Minimal working code which you can put in one file and run `python script.py` without creating project.

```
import scrapy
import json


class MainSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    
    name = 'main'
    # allowed_domains = ['longandfoster.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.longandfoster.com/include/ajax/api.aspx?op=SearchAgents&firstname=&lastname=&page=1&pagesize=200']

    def parse(self, response):
        resp = json.loads(json.loads(response.body)['Entity'])
        for each in resp:
            name = each.get('DisplayName')

            yield {
                "Name": name,
            }

# --- run without project and save in `output.csv` ---

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    # save in file CSV, JSON or XML
    'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',     # csv, json, xml
    'FEED_URI': 'output.csv', #
})
c.crawl(MainSpider)
c.start()
```

Comment: `response.json()`

Comment: @OlvinRoght this gives me error `AttributeError: 'TextResponse' object has no attribute 'json'` - maybe in `requests` it works but not in `scrapy`